# Kelly's maximum for G(f)

Tags: finance-mathematics, statistical-finance, kelly-criterion

In Thorpe's [paper](http://www.edwardothorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/TheKellyCriterionAndTheStockMarket.pdf), Thorpe derives the Kelly criterion

$$f^* = p - q$$

and plugs this into the equation

$$G(f^*) = p \times \log(1+f^*) + q \times \log(1-f^*)$$

to get the following expression

$$G(f^*) = p \times \log (p) + q \times \log (q) + \log(2).$$

I am struggling to derive this result. I am left with

$$p \times \log(p) + q \times \log(q) + p \times \log\left(1 + (1-q)/p\right) + q \times \log \left(1 + (1-p)/q\right).$$
I expect the last two terms somehow equal $\log(2)$ but I have been scratching my head for hours trying to get there. Can anyone show me how please?

Comment: Remember that $q=1-p$

Comment: Perfect thanks, noob2. I had noted the relationship, but needed your nudge to connect the dots.